# How do I create a tile-based footprint trail?

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics, tilemap, path

Currently I am working on a quick game for some friends, but I don't know the proper name for this type of game, so [here is an example of the mechanic in The Lion King II](https://youtu.be/eDHP-PD_YLw?t=176):

[image]

To unlock the exit, you need to cover the ground with paw prints and not get caught by enemies.

I am trying to recreate the footprint-path covering part but I don't know if this has a proper name/term or not and can't find any tutorials to get started.

Currently I have created several planes with the footprint texture going in either direction, and my plan is that when the player walks on it, depending on the direction, will make the appropriate texture appear, then something will check when the path is entirely covered, before setting the exit door to inactive.

Comment: It sounds like you have a workable solution figured out. How have you tried implementing this solution, and where specifically did you get stuck, or get outcomes different than you intended? Also, are you doing this in raw C#, or are you using Unity?

Comment: ... Or Godot, or OpenTK, or MonoGame...? - If none, what graphic API? Unlikely this is pure GDI+, or is it? - Note: I'm assuming 2D, given the example.

Comment: @DMGregory What I am currently trying is I have an OnTriggerEnter that sets the MeshRenderer for the footprint textures to turn active when the player collides with them. The problem is, I'm not sure how I can do a sort of checklist for when all the footprints in an area are set to active, so that the door to the next area opens.

Comment: @Theraot This minigame is set in 3D with 3D models but the camera is set into place for the same POV as in the example video provided.

Comment: I've tagged your question "Unity" since it sounds like that's what you're using. Please ensure you include all of this relevant information in your question in future.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you, I forgot to add that tag myself.

Comment: Since your levels are static, don't you know already before how many tiles are needed to open the door? Just increase a counter for every time you add the renderer on your path and compare the counter against total amount needed for opening the door.